# MDX Query for SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have no idea about the MDX query. I am trying to generate a query for data retrieved in Excel from cubes connected through SQL Server Analysis Services.

Can I use the OLAP Pivot Table extension used to generate the MDX query?  Is it safe to install from [here](https://olappivottableextensions.github.io/)

How else can I generate an MDX query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote OLAP PivotTable Extensions. It is open source so if you have concerns about it’s safety feel free to study the [source](https://github.com/OlapPivotTableExtensions/OlapPivotTableExtensions). The latest release download gets flagged as not being commonly downloaded because it’s new I assume.

OLAP PivotTable Extensions will show you the MDX query which a PivotTable over SSAS is running. Is that what you meant by “generate”?